# JavaScript - table with select, doesn't readjust on cells row span

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

In my program table I'm struggling to adjust the rowspan properly based on the selection. Each selection will have a different rowspan. I have various things not functioning like I'd hoped. Please I'm new to Javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
function tblAdjust(el, val) {
  var shopids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27];
  var shopls = [60, 45, 75, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60, 60];
  var len = 0;
  var pos = 0;
  for (x = 0; x < shopids.length; x++) {
    if (val == shopids[x]) {
      len = shopls[x];
      pos = shopids[x];
    }
  }
  var row = el.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  var col = el.parentNode.cellIndex;
  var span = el.parentNode.rowSpan;
  var rowspan = len / 15;
  if (span == 1) {
    for (x = 0; x < rowspan - 1; x++) {
      var trow = document.getElementById('tblB').rows[row + x];
      trow.deleteCell(col);
    }
    el.parentNode.rowSpan = rowspan;
  }
  if (span != 1 && span == rowspan) {
    alert('equal');
  }
  if (span != 1 && span != rowspan && span > rowspan) {
    //alert('rowspan is greater');
    el.parentNode.rowSpan = 1;
    for (x = row + 2; x < span - 1; x++) {
      var trow = document.getElementById('tblB').rows[row + x];
      var xy = trow.insertCell(col);
      //xy.innerHTML='<select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>...</select>';
    }
    el.parentNode.rowSpan = rowspan;
  }
  if (span != 1 && span != rowspan && span < rowspan) {
    alert('rowspan is smaller');
    for (x = 0; x < rowspan - 1; x++) {
      var trow = document.getElementById('tblB').rows[row + x];
      trow.deleteCell(col);
    }
    el.parentNode.rowSpan = rowspan;
  }
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="customTbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pool A</th>
      <th>Pool B</th>
      <th>Pool C</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tblB">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
      <td>
        <select name="Shop" onchange="tblAdjust(this,this.value)" required>
    <option value="1">Something Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Something Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Something Option 3</option>
   </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please create a minimal example of the problem - you shouldn't expect someone to wade through all this

Comment: The example does not contain element with id ***tblB*** which you are trying to find and throws an error when you select something. Please make [mcve].

Comment: @Emile don't remove the stack snippet, now we can not run the code here :-/

Comment: @Esko Hi :)
Changed that, thanks. I didn't know I removed it

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to achieve (from a user's point of view)? I've looked at the code and I can't fathom the goal of your code, so I can't comment on how to fix it

Comment: @K Scandrett
Hi, In the table each select will have a list of workshops to select and each workshop will have a time. The table is so that the can create their own timetable for the day. Based on the time, the rowspan adjusts to 60 min/15 min to give me the rowspan of 4. Each row in the table represents 15 min.
I can also email you the whole thing, which will give a more precise idea of what I'm trying to do.